# Unexplained radio button positioning in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

This is a 'nit', but it's driving me nuts.  I'm trying to position three radio buttons in a Label Frame.  The radio buttons all have the same padding, but the spacing between buttons 1 and 2 is about 1.5x more than between 2 and 3, using the exact same code.

I keep getting a 'Forbidden' error when trying to paste a screenshot of the issue so cannot show the actual image.  Any ideas what would cause that?  I am letting Tkinter place everything using grid.

```
    self.lf_PlotOptions = LabelFrame(self.lf_AnalysisFunctions, padx=0, pady=0, font="{Arabic Transparent} 16 {bold}", text="Plotting Options")
    self.lf_PlotOptions.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=NW, columnspan=2)

    self.lb_PlotOptions = Label(self.lf_PlotOptions, text="Plot Duration")
    self.lb_PlotOptions.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=10, sticky=NW)

    self.rb_OneYear = tk.Radiobutton(self.lf_PlotOptions, text="1 yr.", variable=self.v_PlotTimeFrame, value=12)
    self.rb_OneYear.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
    self.rb_TwoYears = tk.Radiobutton(self.lf_PlotOptions, text="2 yr.", variable=self.v_PlotTimeFrame, value=24)
    self.rb_TwoYears.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
    self.rb_ThreeYears = tk.Radiobutton(self.lf_PlotOptions, text="3 yr.", variable=self.v_PlotTimeFrame, value=36)
    self.rb_ThreeYears.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Column 0 contains both the Label and the first Radiobutton, and will be as wide as the wider of the two - which is apparently the Label.  Give the Label a `columnspan=` of 2 or 3, so that it isn't needlessly making that one column wider than otherwise required.

Comment: Of course!  Thanks, didn't even think about the label.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Comment: Can you answer it without typing in the answer (since it's explained here).. just want to see the green checkmark.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Gave the Label a columnspan= of 2 or 3, so that it isn't needlessly making that one column wider than otherwise required, per suggestion.